# How do i know whether an update to Chromium browser is available from the command line?

Tags: pi-4, raspbian-buster, chromium

My RP4 is currently running Chromium 88.0.4324.187 on Raspbian 10.  How do I find out whether an update to Chromium is available (and what version it is) without actually installing the update?

Comment: not a question about Raspberry Pi specifically ... it's a Linux question ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885820/how-can-i-check-the-version-before-installing-a-package-using-apt-get

Comment: @jsotola Perfect.  That answers my question.  So it seems like there has been no updates to Chromium since the day Raspberry Pi 4 shipped.

Comment: `apt` should regularly checking for updates of all software. Unless you did a manual installation of chrome (don't do that).